# Changing data(payload) but keeping the same session in python requests post

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, post, python-requests

I am trying to make **ONE** session and keeps it alive for the whole iteration of payload.

The problem is if I make a session then iterate the payload, the session would also be iterated so I wouldn't get any benefit of using a session.

This is my code:

```
while i > 1 and i < 1570:
    i += 1
    payload = {
        'number1': i,
    }
    
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your session and sending your request are two separated steps, so you can totally have one session for your script and send several requests with it:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    while i > 1 and i < 1570:
        i += 1
        payload = {
            'number1': i,
        }

        r = s.post(url, data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
```